# Use EdmFunctionAttribute without exposing Entity Framework dependency/implementation details?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, dependencies

Is there a good way to leverage `EdmFunctionAttribute` without introducing a dependency on The Entity Framework/System.Data.Entity.dll?

I thought I could have an interface with a method and a concrete implementation that implements the method using `EdmFunctionAttribute` to map it to a database function.

I have a context interface `IMyContext` defined in an assembly and an Entity Framework implementation `MyContext` in another assembly.

```
public interface IMyContext
{
    double SomeFunction(double first, double second);

    // other interface details here
}

public partial class MyContext : IMyContext
{
    [EdmFunction("MyNamespace", "MyDatabaseFunction")]
    public double SomeFunction(double first, double second)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method may only be called as part of a LINQ expression.");
    }

    // rest of interface implementation here
}
```

I use a factory (using StructureMap behind the scenes) to get a context instance as the interface type:

```
using (IMyContext context = ContextFactory.GetNewContext())
{
    var results = context.Table.Select(t => context.SomeFunction(t.Col1, t.Col2)).ToList();
}
```

This throws a `NotSupportException` saying that LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double SomeFunction(Double, Double)'.

If I cast the context to the concrete implementation

```
using (MyContext context = ContextFactory.GetNewContext() as MyContext)
{
    ...
}
```

then it works, but then I am required to specify the concrete implementation, which I do not want to do.

The function doesn't have to be a member of the context class, I just put it there for exploring.

Comment: I'm facing the very same situation.  I, too, was hoping that the EdmFunctionAttribute would be resolved when accessed via an interface reference, but to no avail.  It becomes even more difficult when working with  multiple contexts (multiple databases).

Comment: For what it's worth, I couldn't solve this issue and had to slap the DB function on the concrete implementation of my Repository (Context in your case), which means all function calls must reside within my Repository class -- i.e.: my client code couldn't access it directly.  I'm not thrilled with it, but it works (and it forces querying code to reside within the Repository, which some would argue is where it belongs).

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use [Generic Repository Pattern](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sample+generic+repository+pattern+entity+framework) and expose `IQueryable` inteface as a method there, like:

```
IQueryable FindAll(Func<T,bool> exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Linq query builder will investigate the interface type and not the concrete class. The expression tree will contain method reference of method of interface and when you investigate attributes on the method, it will not return any attributes.

You can create an Expression Visitor and visit your expression tree and change the type from interface to concrete type.

```
TypeReplacer tr = new TypeReplacer();
tr.Visit(ex);

class TypeReplacer: ExpressionVisitor{
    protected override MethodCallExpression MethodCall(MethodCallExpression exp)
    {
       // compare exp.Method and 
       // replace it with concrete Type's method
       return exp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't solve anything that wasn't already implemented in the question. Your solution still requires a reference to the concrete context class instead of the context interface.